# Base and sub type serialization in .NET Core 3.1 API using generated C# client

Tags: asp.net-core, swagger, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

We'd like to have a base type like `Input` with a `Value` property and then have `TextInput` which additionally has a `Placeholder` property. The next sub type could be `NumberInput` and it could have a `MaxLength` property for example... To set up inheritance with Swagger and to have it also using the generated client we did that after `services.AddControllers.()`:

```
.AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
 options.SerializerSettings.TypeNameHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.TypeNameHandling.All)
```

Later:

```
           services.AddSwaggerGen(
                options =>
                {
                    options.IncludeXmlComments(XmlCommentsFilePath);
                    options.EnableAnnotations(true);
                    options.UseAllOfForInheritance();
                    options.UseOneOfForPolymorphism();

//even tried that
                    options.SelectDiscriminatorNameUsing((baseType) => "Input");
                    options.SelectDiscriminatorValueUsing((subType) => subType.Name);
```

On the models themselves right now there are no annotations... Tried using this on the base `Input` class definition:

```
[SwaggerSubTypes(new Type[] { typeof(TextInput), typeof(NumberInput)}, Discriminator="Type")]
```

But to be honest I'm not sure what to do with the Discriminator... it adds "Type" automatically as a property.

Calling the API the response is fine but the issue is that the generated C# client cannot deserialize...the properties it returns have `OneOf` prefixed to their name and they have no values...the schema looks good...

Does anyone understand how to make a simple implementation of a base and subtype work with the API and the generated C# client? I can't seem to fully understand this and make it work...